# A potential definition of weak $\omega$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, homotopy-type-theory

This question was inspired by the Homotopy Type Theory Book.

> Might we define a weak $\omega$-category as described below?
>
> Is any similar approach already considered in the literature?

Let $\def\Ob{{\rm Ob}\,} \Ob\mathcal C$  be a set [class] with partial functions $\def\dom{\rm dom} \def\cod{\rm cod} \dom,\cod$ defined on a subset $\mathcal C'\subseteq\Ob\mathcal C$ (i.e. $\dom,\cod:\mathcal C'\to\Ob\mathcal C$). We write of course $f:A\to B$ for $\dom(f)=A,\ \cod(f)=B$ and elements of $\mathcal C'$ are also called *arrows*. 
We require a *composition* of consecutive arrows and *identity arrows*, satisfying  associativity and unit constraintments with coherence isomorphisms such that the coherence diagrams commute *up to equivalence*. 
(Objects $A$ and $B$ are *equivalent* if there is a binary tree of objects $X_{\bf t}$ and arrows $f_{\bf t}$, ${\bf t}\in\{0,1\}^*$ such that 
$X_0=A,\ \ X_1=B,\ \ \ f_{{\bf t}0}:X_{{\bf t}0}\to X_{{\bf t}1},\ \ 
f_{{\bf t}1}:X_{{\bf t}1}\to X_{{\bf t}0}$
where objects $X_{{\bf t}00},\ X_{{\bf t}01},\ X_{{\bf t}10},\ X_{{\bf t}11}$ are defined to be $f_{{\bf t}1}\circ f_{{\bf t}0} $, $\ 1_{X_{{\bf t}0}}$,
$f_{{\bf t}0}\circ f_{{\bf t}1} $, $\ 1_{X_{{\bf t}1}}$; so that $A\simeq B \iff \exists f:A\to B,\ g:B\to A\,$ s.t. $\,g\circ f\simeq 1_A,\ f\circ g\simeq 1_B$) 
To formulate these, we also need a *horizontal composition* functor, from the full substructure of $\mathcal C'\times\mathcal C'$ generated by consecutive pairs of arrows as objects, to $\mathcal C'$. 
(For first,) globularity is assumed (i.e., $\alpha:f\to g$ with $f,g\in\mathcal C'$ implies $\cod(f)=\cod(g)$ and $\dom(f)=\dom(g)$).

Objects are $0$-cells, and an arrow $f:A\to B$ is regarded an $n+1$-cell whenever $A$ and $B$ are $n$-cells. [Note that an $n$-cell is automatically also $k$-cell for any $k<n$.]

More details can be found in my [note](http://renyi.hu/~aladar/potential-definition-weak.pdf).

Comment: The central unsolved problem of all these "algebraic" definitions of weak omega-categories is to give the right space of morphisms between these objects. The obvious morphisms that preserve all the algebraic structure are typically too strict. If one wants to use them to model weak omega-functors, one needs to have a method to resolve the domain, hence one needs a minimum of homotopy theory on the given naive category of weak omega-categories.

Comment: Once one has a candidate definition of this, one needs to check that the homotopy type of maps between any two weak n-categories for finite n is equivalent to what it is supposed to be, as known from the non-algebraic definitions that work. This has not been done for any of the many proposals for algebraically defined weak omega-categories, as far as I am aware.

Comment: To add to what Urs wrote, I think a main proposed technique is a method of cofibrant replacement for the domain so that weak morphisms are identified with strict morphisms out of the cofibrant replacement. It is quite true that this area is sadly underdeveloped (and it's something I mean to return to, someday).

Comment: A major problem with this method is that compositions in the 3rd, 4th... directions don't automatically arise, which would be expected in higher categories.

Comment: Isn't this almost exactly the same as strict $\omega$ categories (defined by R. Street)?